# What is the right camera lens for imaging this experiment?

Tags: experimental-technique, camera

I am conducting an experiment in our lab where we are using an ICCD camera to image a very short-duration (ns) physical phenomenon. The area of interest of the test is about 25mm x 25mm and I need to situate the camera about 1m away (I can't get closer than that, due to equipment constraints). I would like to arrange the optics so that the area of interest completely fills the camera sensor, to make the best use of the available resolution; however, I am not very knowledgeable about camera equipment and not sure what would be the correct lens to use, to achieve that.

Can anyone recommend what sort of lens I would need to give the best image in this situation? I assume I will probably need some sort of zoom lens?

Comment: I would do all of (1) look at all camera  manufacturers applications web pages, (2) find papers about imaging onto ccd's etc (3) get hold of some optics software to simulate your experiment,(5) ask around your department/university to see if anyone has had experience of doing this in the in the past.  Good luck :)